# Regex don't see last line

Tags: regex, kotlin

Why if take this regex my two last lines don't matches but only the last should not compare to this

```
Regex("""((([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d|60):([0-5]\d|60))\n)+""")
```

and when I write like this

```
Regex("""((([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d|60):([0-5]\d|60))\n?)+""")
```

the last line dont fit this regex

my text is

```
13:15:19
07:26:57
10:00:03
19:56:14
13:15:19
00:40:31
```

i read it from file and then match them like this

```
val format = Regex("""(([0-1]\d:|2[0-4]:)([0-5]\d|60)(:[0-5]\d|60)(\n)?)+""")
        .matches(File(inputName).readText())
```

but it's not properly because if between two lines not contains \n  it will not fit by formats and like i have said before even this regex dont see last line . What i do wrong? i have done with this code already but wont to know what wrong with another solution

```
File(inputName).readLines().map { it ->
    val f = Regex("""(([0-1]\d:|2[0-4]:)([0-5]\d|60)(:[0-5]\d|60)(\n)?)""")
            .matches(it)
    if (!f) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("File format")
    }
}
```

[this two lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOReW.png)

```
val ss = "00:40:31\n" +
        "07:26:57\n" +
        "10:00:03\n" +
        "13:15:19\n" +
        "13:15:19\n" +
        "19:56:14"
println(Regex("""(([0-1]\d:|2[0-4]:)([0-5]\d|60)(:[0-5]\d|60)(\n|$))+""")
        .matches(ss))
println(File(inputName).readText())
val format = Regex("""(([0-1]\d:|2[0-4]:)([0-5]\d|60)(:[0-5]\d|60)(\n|$))+""")
        .matches(File(inputName).readText())
println(format)
```

Comment: Post multiple examples of which cases you want to match and which not and why should not match.

Comment: with first regex the last stroke in text should not match but other do. With second regex all should matches. but in first case the last two strokes dont match and in second case the last stroke dont match

Comment: What do you mean by "stroke"? (In typography, *that's* a stroke: "/". Your input does not have that.)

Comment: sorry i mean line

Comment: Your first examples have the + behind the closing bracket of the `regex(...)`, you know...

Comment: If you want to catch the end of a line, use `$`, not `\n`.

Comment: @Nyerguds I add code when i match text from file and not from file. In first case programm show true in second false. My file looks like text in my post. Extension of file .txt. Can you say pls why it dont show true from  file?

Comment: When I try your regex, all lines match.